# How do I use dual monitors for one image?

Tags: windows-8, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have a dual monitor set up.
But I can't figure out how to put one image across both of them.
Like if I want to watch a youtube video, it will only display on one screen instead of stretching across both of them.

I googled it and one page said right click on the desktop and click screen resolution and then choose stretch.
When I do that, the orientation options are only portrait and landscape. The multiple displays options are extend desktop, duplicate desktop or show only one desktop and black out the other one. There is no stretch. 
Duplicate desktop just mirrors the desktop on both screens. Extend desktop is just like having two work stations.
I'm on windows 8 and I have a gtx 750ti.
Another page said that they have to be the same resolution. My screens are. They're both 1920*1080

Answer (score 1):

Use the "extend desktop" option.

If you're using a web browser to view, don't maximize the window, set it to a windowed, non-full screen state, then drag the side of the window to the other monitor, it should then span the two.  Then size the width and height manually.

Comment: Can I stretch apps too? Or only windowed browsers?

Comment: any resizable windows app should allow it to span monitors, but that doesn't mean it will use the full space unless it was written to detect it's window size. try it, can't break anything.